# Can having a 'setter'/instance variable lead to race conditions with singleton DAOs?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring, singleton, race-condition

Assume the following class is a singleton

```
public class myDAO {
    //determines the tableName and Id column names to based on itemType
    private String itemType;
    public void setItemType(String itemType) {...} 

    //Following methods use itemType to customize their queries
    public boolean findObj(int id){...} 
    public boolean deleteObj(int id){...}
    public boolean updateObj(Obj obj){...}
    //etc...
}
```

The code was recently refactored with the setter, thus giving the DAO some state. I'm seeing that this is configured as `singleton-scope` in Spring's config file. I have a strange feeling that this could lead to potential race conditions. Is that correct?

I'm really not sure if this is indeed the case but it'd be a nightmarish situation to figure it out, IMHO if it were true. I know this may not be the best possible design but I just wanted to know if this could lead to race conditions when concurrent threads are querying for different `itemTypes`. I was thinking of changing the scope to `prototype` but am not sure if it's indeed required in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If multiple threads are calling `setItemType(...)` and then calling `findObj(...)` and are expecting to find the object with an id *and* with the item-type then yes, your strange feeling is correct, this is a potential race condition and won't work in a multi-threaded application.

You should instead pass in the `itemType` to each of your methods:

```
public boolean findObj(String itemType, int id){...} 
public boolean deleteObj(String itemType, int id){...}
public boolean updateObj(String itemType, Obj obj){...}
```

If the itemType is set just once after the DAO has been constructed by Spring then this is okay but should be done as part of your Spring configuration which is done single-threaded.

If you have to add an `itemType` argument to all or most of the methods then it seems to me that you no longer should have a singleton.  Instead you should consider having a DAO factory or something and have multiple DAO instances, each with their own item-type.

Answer (score 2):

If the `setItemType` method is *only* used on initialization (e.g. via Spring configuration) and if Spring enforces appropriate memory barriers to make sure the value is visible in all threads before use, then it's probably okay - but a bit of a smell. This is where constructor injection is neater, as you could then make it a `final` variable, which clearly isn't as much of a problem.

If the `setItemType` method is used *post* initialization, then that's definitely, *definitely* an issue. You'll either need multiple instances all over the place (e.g. one per class which needs a reference to a DAO) or potentially one instance per item type: declare several separate beans, then give each class which needs a DAO a reference to the "right" one depending on which type it needs.